# Pass objects between components

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

I've intend to do the following with my objects. Hopefully, eventhough the code does not work, you'll understand the intention.

I have this component with the following coordinates in Nested.svelte:

```
<script lang=ts>
    export let pos: {
        x: number,
        y: number,
    }
</script>
```

Each nested component in my program is shown as following in App.svelte:

```
{#each objects as object}
    <Nested bind:pos.x={object.geometry.x} bind:pos.y={object.geometry.y}
{/each}
```

The `objects` variable is a store value with the following structure:

```
objects.geometry = [
    {
        x,
        y,
    }, {
        x,
        y,
    } ...
]
```

The problem is in sending the `objects.geometry.x` and `objects.geomtry.y` to the Nested component from the App. The following code i have given does not work, and the only solution i found to work is sending the object as a whole: `<Nested bind:pos={objects.geometry}>`. This solution does not let me bind specific values in App to specific values in Nested. This also forces me to name the variables in the `objects` variable the same names as the coordinate values in Nested.svelte (`x` and `y`).

Is there another way to send object-structured data into components? Something that would work like `<Nested bind:pos.x={object.geometry.x} bind:pos.y={object.geometry.y}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is export your `x` and `y` and build your own `pos` variable from it like so:

```
export let x;
export let y;

$: pos = new Proxy({x, y}, {
    set: (_obj, key, value) => {
        if (key === "x") x = value;
        else if (key === "y") y = value;
        else return false;
        return true
    }
})
```

[repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/109a632d962f4cd296f377583325c1c8?version=3.49.0)
(If you didnt need to write to `pos`, you could also use `$: pos = { x, y };` which will stay up to date, but since you used bind I assume you want a two way binding)

But I would suggest just using `x` and `y`.

Comment: The `pos` proxy breaks as soon as the data is updated from the outside. It could also be declared reactive, though.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't test that - the `pos` was stayed correct but didn't update the ui - I changed `pos` to be declared reactive as you suggested, this way we also don't need the get

Comment: I worked further on my code, and got around this problem, so this is not a problem anymore for me. But thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported.

You either have to not use a binding (you rarely should use those anyway), then you can inline an object:

```html
{#each objects as object}
    <Nested pos={{ x: object.geometry.x, y: object.geometry.y }} />
{/each}
```

Or you have to split `pos` into top level props `x`/`y`.

Comment: Okay, so to keep the reading of the code as simple as possible while maintaining functionality, it seems like i need to pass the object, which works, so no problem. Thanks for the answer!